# Why is git committing on merge, even after "git config --global merge.commit no"?

Tags: git, merge, commit

I'm using git 2.39.2 on macOS 10.15.7

I ran the following:

```
git config --global merge.commit no
git config --global merge.ff no
```

So my ~/.gitconfig now looks like this:

```
# This is Git's per-user configuration file.
[user]
    name = myname
    email = myemail@example.com
[http]
    postBuffer = 1048576000
[merge]
    commit = no
    ff = no
```

But still, when I run the following:

```
git switch main
git merge feature
```

It automatically brings me into a commit message editor.

Running `git merge --no-commit feature` still works as expected and gives me:

```
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
```

But why doesn't it do that without `--no-commit` when I have `commit = no` in my ~/.gitconfig settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why doesn't it do that without --no-commit when I have commit = no in my ~/.gitconfig settings?

Because there is no `merge.commit` config variable. You can set any key you want in your config, but it won't *do* anything unless some piece of code recognizes it. There's no mention of `merge.commit` anywhere in the git source or documentation.

Comment: Is there a different config variable that I should be setting to have `--no-commit` all the time?  Or do I just have to include `--no-commit` with every merge command?

Comment: No, there's no such variable. An alias (as described in a now unfortunately deleted answer) is your best shot. You're free to choose a *shorter* name for it if you like :)

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for the answer.  I think I'll just get in the habit of remembering the full command for now.